# MySQL command to grant user privileges to read all tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

GRANT SELECT
ON * .* 
TO 'bob'@'192.168.16.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Is this correct ?

Comment: You will find it helpful to check [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/). Did you try running what you wrote?

Comment: Yes I did, I checked the documentation already

Comment: Then did you try running the code you wrote?

Comment: Yes of course I did.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that then on your question. That you have written this query and that it failed/worked. We don't know if it works or not cause you didn't say it.

Comment: Your GRANT statement is correct so if the connection doesn't work then check the IP of the client machine that's trying to connect to the mysql server.  'bob'@'192.168.16.%' means bob can connect to the mysql server from any machine having an IP range of 192.168.16.%. If you are connecting form the same machine then try 'bob'@'localhost'. Also try specifying a password if required, by appending the GRANT statement with  " IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' "

Comment: When granting user bob to read all tables is it also acceptable to say:                                                                   GRANT SELECT ON employees.*                                                                    TO 'bob'@'192.168.16.%';                                                            FLUSH PRIVILEGES;